# What is the purpose of the Manage Display in Content type?

Tags: 8, entities

For example, in the Body field there is a **LABEL** with the following values:
[image]

And there is **FORMAT** with such values:

[image]

How does something change on the site depending on the selected values in the Manage Display and what does each value mean?
I tried to create my Content and change these values in Manage Display. But nothing happens to my Content and it doesn’t change at all. Although I tried to choose different view mode.

Comment: Did you flush the cache? Because it's pretty self-explaining when you see it. You then also can have different view modes and then for the default use the fully body and when the node is displayed in a different view mode in a view for example only have the trimmed summary body.

Comment: Those settings only work if your template files render fields correctly using the `content` render array. It will not work if you bypass the render pipeline using something like `node.field_foo.value` in your template.

Comment: Yes, you are dictating how fields will render out. If you render the content render array in a node template that's what happens. If you use raw values, you won't see anything change.